# How to test this component / template ? :)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angularjs-components

I looking for any help with my problem about my UNITEST for AngularJS (and nvd3).

Indeed, when I try to make my chart I have an error.
It's like `$ctrl.data` and `$ctrl.options` were completly empty ...

I dont understand where is the problem  and I tried to unlock this the all day without success ..

If someone has an idea of where come the problem I thank in advance.

The code :

myComp.comp.js :

```
angular.module('myMod')
        .component('myComp', {
            template: '<div><nvd3 options="$ctrl.options" data="$ctrl.wrapped"></nvd3></div>',
            bindings: {
                data: '<',
                zoom: '<'
            },
            controller: myCtrl
        })

myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope']
function myCtrl($scope) {
    //Here I set wrapped with data
    //and set the options for nvd3
}
```

myComp.spec.js :

```
describe('component: myComp', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myComp'));

    var $ctrl,
        $bindings,
        $template,
        scope,
        elmt;

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $componentController, $rootScope, $document) {

        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        $bindings = {
            zoom: true,
            data: [ /*DATA SAMPLE HERE*/ ]
        }

        $ctrl = $componentController('myComp', $scope, $bindings);
        elmt = angular.element('my-comp data="$ctrl.data" zoom="$ctrl.zoom"></my-comp>');
        elmt = $compile(elmt)($scope);

        $scope.$apply();
    }));

    it("test", function () {
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Karma / Jasmine :

```
Chrome 53.0.2785 (Mac OS X 10.12.0) component: myComp test FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'ordinal' of undefined
        at Object.nv.models.multiBarHorizontal (bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js:8823:23)
        at Object.nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart (bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js:9180:30)
        at Object.updateWithOptions (bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js:106:72)
        at Object.refresh (bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js:53:39)
        at bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js:449:68
        at bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js:517:43
        at Scope.$digest (bower_components/angular/angular.js:17524:23)
        at Scope.$apply (bower_components/angular/angular.js:17790:24)
        at Object.<anonymous> (ml.report/variableImportances/variableImportances.spec.js:38:9)
        at Object.invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4718:19)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3047:25)
        at Suite.<anonymous> (myComp.comp.js:'XX':'XX')
        at myComp.spec.js:'XX':'XX'
        at myComp.spec.js:'XX':'XX'
        /* I have put 'XX' in place of the real lines / col
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the opening `<` in your template sample.

However, if you are using `$componentController` you don't need to compile any template, so either do:

```
$ctrl = $componentController('myComp', $scope, $bindings);
```

Or, do:

```
$scope.zoom = true;
$scope.data = [ /*DATA SAMPLE HERE*/ ];
elmt = angular.element('<my-comp data="data" zoom="zoom"></my-comp>');
elmt = $compile(elmt)($scope);

$scope.$apply();
$ctrl = elmt.controller('myComp');
```